# Calling oracle package from mulesoft

Tags: mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I have a requirement where I need to call a oracle stored procedure that is inside a package. I found lot of samples which explains about calling the procedure and successfully tried that.
But when I try to do the same with a procedure that is inside a package, I am getting **ORA-06576 : Not a valid function or procedure name** as error.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Please add to your question the XML for the database connector operation that calls the stored procedure, and the definition of the stored procedure interface, in text.

Comment: Its in my project environment which I should not / cannot copy. But will that be helpful, because there is no issue with connector configuration , because, connection is successful and I can execute a sample procedure that is not inside a package.

Comment: The object of the error is the call to the stored procedure. Probably a syntax error. Without seeing it probably no one can help you. Maybe you can add just a snippet without any confidential details.